# Tell jQuery to execute the action set in the value attribute

Tags: javascript, jquery

As an example of that, considering this code:

```
<input id="1" class="ok" type="radio" name="myradio" value="hide">
<input id="2" class="ok" type="radio" name="myradio" value="show">
<input id="3" class="ok" type="radio" name="myradio" value="fadeOut">
<input id="4" class="ok" type="radio" name="myradio" value="fadeIn">
```

I want the same output of the following code but without `if` statements.

```
if($('#1').is(':checked')) {$("#myDiv").hide()}
if($('#2').is(':checked')) {$("#myDiv").show()}
if($('#3').is(':checked')) {$("#myDiv").fadeOut()}
if($('#4').is(':checked')) {$("#myDiv").fadeIn()}
```

In other words, I want to tell jQuery to execute the action set in the `value` attribute, as long as it is a valid jQuery action, without using if statements.

PS: `myDiv` could be anything, for example this:

```
<div id="myDiv">bla bla bla</div>
```

Comment: Where is `#myDiv`?

Comment: There's more than one way to call a function.

Comment: It could be any div, this one for example:

   `<div id="myDiv">bla bla bla</div>`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Get the value of the input and use bracket syntax `[]` to access the function. And after them put `()` to call the function. And also put validation

```js
$('input[type=radio]').on('click', function(){
  var action = this.value;
  
  if($('#myDiv')[action]){
    $('#myDiv')[action]();  
  }       
  
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input id="1" class="ok" type="radio" name="myradio" value="hide">
<input id="2" class="ok" type="radio" name="myradio" value="show">
<input id="3" class="ok" type="radio" name="myradio" value="fadeOut">
<input id="4" class="ok" type="radio" name="myradio" value="fadeIn">

<div id="myDiv">
  TEST  
</div>
```

Comment: `this.value` rather than `$(this).val()`, but otherwise yes.

Comment: Was about to do this, just want to add one thing which I had in my answer was, validate these before executing using an array of these methods and `indexOf()`

Comment: @DavidThomas why `this.value` instead of `$(this).val()`? Only for performance?

Comment: Sort of, I suppose, I just don't see the point of invoking jQuery to do something that's so functional and effective, working across various, if not all, browsers.